defineProps withDefaults "Type is missing the following properties from type"
I have a Button component with the following code:
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { computed, ref } from 'vue';

const {
  type = 'button',
  color = 'primary',
  disabled = false
} = defineProps<{
  href?: string;
  type: 'button' | 'submit' | 'reset' | undefined;
  color: string;
  disabled: boolean;
}>();

const element = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null);

defineExpose({
  focus: () => {
    element.value?.focus();
  },
});

const style =
  'inline-flex justify-center rounded-sm shadow-sm px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus:outline focus:outline-2 focus:outline-offset-2';

const colors = new Map([
  [
    'primary',
    'bg-lime-600 text-white hover:bg-lime-700 focus-visible:outline-lime-700 focus:outline-lime-700',
  ],
  [
    'base',
    'bg-neutral-600 text-white hover:bg-neutral-700 focus-visible:outline-neutral-700  focus:outline-neutral-700',
  ],
  [
    'red',
    'bg-red-600 text-white hover:bg-red-700 focus-visible:outline-red-700 focus:outline-red-700',
  ],
  [
    'white',
    'bg-white text-neutral-900 ring-1 ring-inset ring-neutral-300 hover:bg-neutral-50 focus-visible:outline-neutral-400 focus:outline-neutral-400',
  ],
]);

const disabledStyles = computed(() =>
  disabled ? ' opacity-50 cursor-not-allowed' : null
);

const styles = computed(
  () => `${style} ${colors.get(color)}${disabledStyles.value}`
);
</script>
<template>
  <component :is="href ? 'a' : 'button'" ref="element" :class="styles" v-bind="href ? { href } : { type }">
    <slot />
  </component>
</template>

and I'm using it from within another component as such:
<script lang="ts" setup>
import Button from '@/components/Button.vue';
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';

const emit = defineEmits(['cancel', 'proceed']);

const buttonRef = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null);

onMounted(() => {
  if (buttonRef.value) {
    buttonRef.value.focus();
  }
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    // ...
    <div class="mt-6 grid grid-flow-row-dense grid-cols-2 gap-3">
      <Button ref="buttonRef" @click="emit('cancel')">Abort</Button>
      <Button color="red" @click="emit('proceed')">
        <slot name="button" />
      </Button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

When I compile (using Vite) the code for production I get the error:

Argument of type '{ ref: string; onClick: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ readonly href?: string | undefined; readonly type: "button" | "submit" | "reset" | undefined; readonly color: string; readonly disabled: boolean; } & VNodeProps & ... 4 more ... & Record<...>'.


Type '{ ref: string; onClick: any; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ readonly href?: string | undefined; readonly type: "button" | "submit" | "reset" | undefined; readonly color: string; readonly disabled: boolean; }': type, color, disabled


<Button ref="buttonRef" @click="emit('cancel')">Abort

Cannot figure out how to resolve it so any help would be much appreciated.

How do you compile your app?

Why is it you have href:? ... and no default value for it, yet you don't do type?: ..., color?: ..., disabled?: ... which do have defaults?

^^^ I meant href?: ... of course ... simply adding the ? to those optional (with default) props will fix the issue

I'm compiling with Vite

By declaring
defineProps<{
  href?: string;
  type: 'button' | 'submit' | 'reset' | undefined;
  color: string;
  disabled: boolean;
}>()

You set three required props (type, color, disabled).
However, you don't set these props to your Button component here:
 <Button ref="buttonRef" @click="emit('cancel')">Abort</Button>

Generally, there is thee ways to solve this:

Make the props non-required (by adding a ? after their names, like you did for href (@Jaromanda X already said that in the comments))

Provide Values for your required props: Simply set type, color and disabled.

By changing your compiler options to allow for these inconsistencies to be ignored. (However, you will still receive a warning by vue that you didn't provide a required prop). - I would not recommend this.


In your Case:
color: Provide a value for this or make it non-required with a default (primary?)
disabled: Provide a value for this or make it non-required with a default (false?)
type: I see that you might want type to be required if href does not exist, but non-required vice versa. This is not possible. (Note that I think you can create a strongly type interface for that, but this is complex and I don't think you need it.)
Instead, I would recommend you to use the following props instead of type and href:
isLink: boolean
buttonElementAttrs: { href?: string, type?: 'button' | 'submit' | 'reset' | undefined)
And render your Button Component like this:
<template>
    <component :is="isLink ? 'a' : 'button'" ref="element" :class="styles" v-bind="buttonElementAttrs">
        <slot />
    </component>
</template>

Then you can use this code to show your button:
 <Button ref="buttonRef" @click="emit('cancel')" :isLink="false" :buttonElementAttrs="{ href: 'my/fancy/url' }">Abort</Button>


The 3 properties are defined with default values using withDefaults eliminating the need to add them manually every time you use the component.

Destructuring with defaults is not withDefaults().
Here's how to do it:
interface Props {
  href?: string;
  type: 'button' | 'submit' | 'reset' | undefined;
  color: string;
  disabled: boolean;
}

withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  type: () => 'button',
  color : () => 'primary',
  disabled: () => false,
});


I had it this way, but refactored to the updated code - neither works.
